# How to know the next value of an automatically incremented primary key if all rows were deleted from a table?

Tags: mysql

There is a table which had records but these records were deleted. There is a primary key which is incremented automatically on the database table.

Is there a way to know , before inserting a new row in the table , the next value of this primary key ? If it is not possible is there a way to get the immediately the value of the generated primary key after inserting a row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could insert a row and then look at [`last_insert_id`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

```
insert into ....;
select last_insert_id();
```

That would give you the `auto_increment` value that was used for the INSERT.

You can also try looking at the [`show table status like 'your_table_name'`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-table-status.html) output, there will be an Auto_increment value that should tell you the next one that will be used.

Comment: I have problem calling the LAST_INSERT_ID() method in PHP. I tried $image_id = select LAST_INSERT_ID(); but it does not return anything , then I tried $image_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); and it also returns nothing ! So how to call it in PHP ?

Comment: @Andy: `last_insert_id()` needs to be run inside MySQL, use `mysql_query` and make sure you use the same connection for both the INSERT and SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just sitting at a MySQL prompt, type:

```
show create table my_table;
```

At the bottom you'll see something like:

```
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=876159 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

The AUTO_INCREMENT is what the next id would be.

Answer (score 1):

One more variant -

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM information_schema.`TABLES` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<table_schema>' AND TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>';
```